# Removing person name

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm creating a method to Delete the first instance, p, of a Person with the name Mikel from this Person's friend list and delete this Person from p's friend list. Return true if and only if p was found on this Person's friend list. i run my code but it didn't work, i couldn't figure out the problem. can someone help me.

```
String name;

private ArrayList<Person> friend = new ArrayList<Person>();

public boolean deleteFriend(String Mike)
{
    for (Person p : friend ) {
        if (p.name.equals(Mike)) {
            p.friend.remove(Mike);
            break;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }           
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately "it didn't work" doesn't tell us anything about what you observed vs what you expected. Please clarify your question - and please read the formatting help to make sure your code is formatted appropriately next time.

Comment: We need to see your definition of "Person" because it's not obvious from the code.

Comment: This seems an awful lot like a graph problem. What I suggest you do is: first, parse through Mikel's friends while deleting Mikel from their lists. Once, none of Mikel's friends know that he exists any more, delete Mikel's entry.

Comment: The question says there should be two removals, but you only call `remove` once. Also, that `for` loop doesn't actually loop because you always `break` or `return` in the loop body.

Comment: @DebosmitRay If you `break` immediately after calling `remove` you get no exception. The `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs when you try to continue the iteration.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes sir, of course. Thanks for the clarification though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would write up some pseudo-code to give an idea about what you might want to do. Given that you haven't posted the Person class, this is pretty much all I think I can come up with.

```
public boolean delete(String username) {

    // I don't know what you have implemented to go 
    // from username to Person to friends
    List<Person> usersFriends = getFriends(username);  

    // iterating over Mikel's friends
    for(Person usersFriend: usersFriends) {
        // Mikel's friends friendList
        List<Person> usersFriendsList = usersFriend.friends;

        // Mikel's friend's friendlist
        Iterator usersFriendsListIterator = usersFriendsList.iterator();
        // if Mikel shows up, remove him
        while(usersFriendsListIterator.hasNext()) {
            if(usersFriendsListIterator.next().equals(**username**))
                usersFriendsListIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a well defined `Person` class, you can safely remove and retrieve deletion status by using an iterator:

```
//String s = "Mike" 
//           or whatever;

public boolean deleteFriend (String s){
    Iterator<Person> it = friend.iterator();
    Person p = null;
    boolean found = false;

    while(it.hasNext() && !found){
       p = it.next(); 
       if (p.getName().equals(s)) {it.remove(); found = true;}
    }

    return found;
}
```

If you prefer a shorter version, you can use Java8 internal iterator `removeIf`:

```
public boolean deleteFriendJava8 (String s){
    int initSize = friend.size(); 

    friend.removeIf(p -> p.getName().equals(s));

    return (initSize != friend.size());
}
```

Where `getName()` (in both cases) is a method that returns `Person`'s name. That method should be defined in `Person` class, obviously.

About the instance variable `friend`, you should declare it like this:

```
private List<Person> friend = new ArrayList<>();
```

because this way you increase `friend` abstraction level (you're not limiting `friend` to an ArrayList, which is more specific).